# firebase multi path update

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am trying to update 2 seperate firebase location 1. is a list of patients and 2. is a list of evaluation for that patient. I created a lookup that list all the evaluation for that patient

[image]

I have been using the code below to loop with the evaluation keys, however only the patients location is updating. Please help.

```
function updateLabel ({rootRef, uid, label}){
  var lookupRef = rootRef.child('evaluation_lookup/22')
  return lookupRef.once('value'). then(snap => {
    var evalKeys = Object.keys(snap.val())
    var updateObj = {}
    for (var i=0; i < evalKeys.length; i++) {
      var keys = evalKeys[i]
      updateObj['evaluation/22/keys/label'] = label
    }
    updateObj['patient/22/label'] = label
    return rootRef.update(updateObj)
  })
}
updateLabel ({
  rootRef: firebase.database().ref(),
  uid: '22',
  label: 'yetunde'
}).then(_=> {
  console.log('complete!')
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this snippet:

```
for (var i=0; i < evalKeys.length; i++) {
  var keys = evalKeys[i]
  updateObj['evaluation/22/keys/label'] = label
}
```

Every time through this loop, you're updating the same path: `evaluation/22/keys/label`. You probably want to use the *value* of `keys` in there, so:

```
  updateObj['evaluation/22/'+keys+'/label'] = label
```

Or using a template literal:

```
  updateObj[`evaluation/22/${keys}/label`] = label
```

As an additional change, I'd recommend using `Array.forEach()` to loop over the keys. Or even better, use Firebase's built-in `Snapshot.forEach()`:

```
return lookupRef.once('value'). then(snap => {
  var updateObj = {}
  snap.forEach(function(child) {
    updateObj['evaluation/22/'+child.key+'/label'] = label
  }
  return rootRef.update(updateObj)
})
```